# Word for delimiters which are placed after each item?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, terminology

The word "separator" can be used to describe delimiters which are placed between items. For instance, in this sequence:

"abbbabbbabbbabbba"

The 'b's separate the 'a's.

I'm looking for a word similar to "separator" which can be used to describe delimiters in this sequence:

"abbbabbbabbbabbbabbb"

The 'b's come after each 'a'.

Examples of this are periods after sentences and, in programming, semicolons after statements.

Comment: Terminator. Hasta la vista baby!

Comment: @WillHunting Separators go in-between, the word I'm looking for comes strictly after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say

- terminator (terminator token, terminator character, terminating punctuation etc.)
- end marker (end of line, end of input, end of block, end of statement etc.)
- trailer (trailing token, trailing character, trailing signature (below))

Somewhat more loosely, more appropriate to (binary) file formats, maybe:

- signature (signature bytes, header signature)
- marker

Comment: The problem seems to be that these terms do not suggest the token may also go inside, e.g., *terminator* obviously occurs at the end -- that's it, whereas a delimiter occurs in the middle of a string, delimiting sub-strings. If we are thinking in terms of the sub-string alone, then it might work, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Kris _semantics_ :) That really depends on how you look at it. To me, it 'ends' a subsequence, so indeed it goes at the end. It's just not _the end of the universe_, at once.

Answer (score 1):

At least in the coding/markup world, Google returns over 90 instances of the two word phrase "terminal delimiter", as in

> *The first in each pair is the initial delimiter and the second is the terminal delimiter*

or

> *However, this older version of the join() function also added a terminal delimiter to the end of the sequence*

Answer (score 0):

I would think of it as a special case (hyponym) of *delimiter*.

As we intend to use it exclusively at the end of a string, would it constitute a post-fix?

{(sub-string)(postfix) (sub-string)(postfix) (sub-string)(postfix)}

That will make it a *postfix(ed delimiter)*.

I'm yet to check out if there's already a defined term for this class of delimiter. Might edit in more details if I find any.